# how to make a wrinkled paper background using css

Tags: css

I have a image of a background that looks like a wrinkled paper and I am trying to make the same background using CSS instead of the image.
is that even possible to make using css?
this is the image:
[image]

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/making-static-noise-from-a-weird-css-gradient-bug/

Answer (score -2):

I don't think that this is possible to do with css (at least not efficiently)